# 出生 vs. 出世 differences?

Tags: word-choice, difference

I was watching a Chinese movie about the Monkey King (孙悟空）, and after he sprung out of the rock, he said "我出世了". I looked it up and understood it to mean "I was born". Are the two terms interchangeable or is one more formal than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[出世](http://www.zdic.net/c/a/1e/47123.htm) has more use scenarios than `出生`. When used for people, it's same as `出生` (`出生` is used more commonly for this case); but it could be also used for things which come into being.

> (1) [vouchsafe;come into being;be born]∶人的出生
>
> (2) [come out;be published]∶问世;产生
>
> (3) [be above worldly considerations;be not involved in the material
>   world]∶超脱超脱人世束缚。佛教用语,佛教徒以人世为俗世,故称脱离人世束缚为出世
>
> (4) [rise above this world]∶高出人世

Answer (score 0):

出生 is used for humans and animals mostly. 出世 is used in ancient novels for heroes and great persons, also used for lifeless things like treasures and rarities.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that 出生 means "to be born," that is to emerge from a womb and live on. 出世 means "to be reborn," in the Hindu/Buddhist sense.